# How to display the chapter number in the headers in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, context, context-mkiv

I am using serupheadertexts to define the headers in my document:

```
\setuphead[chapter]                     [number=yes]

\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[chapter]}][][][]
```

I want to access the chapter number, but it is not displaying.

I tried this:

```
\setupheadertexts[{\getnumber[chapter] \getmarking[chapter]}][][][]
```

It does not display any number there.

How can I display the chapter number in the headers in ConTeXt?

Comment: Untested: \getmarking[chapternumber] should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the first, present, and final values of section counters
for the currently active structure component  by their name using the command `\somenamedheadnumber`.

`\somenamedheadnumber` takes two mandatory arguments:

1. the *name* of a structure element, e.~g. *section*, *chapter*, and
2. one of the identifiers *first*, *current*, *last* that determine the
   value to be retrieved.

Examples:

```
%% the initial value of the chapter counter
\somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{first}

%% the number of the final section in the current chapter
\somenamedheadnumber{section}{last}

%% the number of the currently active subsubsection;
%% in the page header this will retrieve the number of the
%% structural last active on the current page
\somenamedheadnumber{subsubsection}{current}
```

As a shorthand, `\namedheadnumber{<name>}` is equivalent to
`\somenamedheadnumber{<name>}{current}`.

A more extensive example showing the various getters for structure
counters in action:

```
\setuppagenumbering [location=footer,alternative=doublesided]

\startsetups header.outer
  Chapter
  \space
  \namedheadnumber{chapter}
  \space of \space
  \somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{last}
  \space --- \space
  {\cap\getmarking[chapter]}
\stopsetups

\startsetups header.inner
  Section
  \space
  \namedheadnumber{section}
  \space of \space
  \somenamedheadnumber{section}{last}
  \space --- \space
  {\italic\getmarking[section]}
\stopsetups

\setupheadertexts
  [\setups{header.outer}]
  [\setups{header.inner}]

\starttext
  \getrandomnumber\i25
  \completecontent\page
  \dorecurse{\i}{
    \getrandomnumber\j27
    \startchapter[title=foo]
      \input knuth
      \dorecurse{\j}{
        \startsection[title=bar]
          \input ward\par\input dawkins
        \stopsection
      }
    \stopchapter
  }
\stoptext
```

Comment: Any reason you are using the low-level `\namedheadnumber` instead of `\getmarking[chapternumber]`? The former is useful if you want to do some processing with the number, but for simply typesetting the result, `\getmarking[...]` is sufficient.

Comment: @Aditya I had issues with ``\getmarking``, iirc it did not yield the intended result.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

The normal way to get the chapter number in the headers is to use `\getmarking[chapternumber]`.

```
\setupheadertexts[{\getmarking[chapternumber]--\getmarking[chapter]}]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={First chapter}, marking={Mark for first chapter}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Second chapter}, marking={Mark for second chapter}]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: `getnumber[chapternumber]` or `getmarking[chapternumber]`. Revise your example please. It's incongruent with first paragraph

Comment: @somenxavier: Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: You're welcome. Is it a way of getting whole number and name? Because if you have no Chapter yet, you get '0' but name ''. Can we get '' if Chapter is not set yet?